# dhcp wi-fi server on raspberry with hostapd without dns forwarding

Tags: wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, dhcp-server, hostapd

I want to use a raspberry pi as a wi-fi server in the following situation:

A laser scanner sensor is connected to it by ethernet, and a service running on the pi should transfer the data to a pair of robots when they so require.

the problem is that EVERY single tutorial out there about using hostapd to create an access point from a raspberry pi includes using dnsmasq to forward the requests to the internet.
I just want them to connect to my server and fetch the data.

Is there any way to set up a simple dhcp server for this purpose?

Comment: You want the pi to be the DHCP server right? Not another device on the network?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Yes